# Using AudioKit and SpriteKit audio simultaneously

Tags: ios, audio, sprite-kit, audiokit

I'm building a game that uses the AudioKit framework to detect the frequency of sound received by the mic. I set it up as follows:

```
import SpriteKit
import AudioKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var mic : AKMicrophone!
    var tracker : AKFrequencyTracker!
    var silence : AKBooster!
    let mixer = AKMixer()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       mic = AKMicrophone()
       tracker = AKFrequencyTracker.init(mic)
       silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
       mixer.connect(silence)
       AudioKit.output = mixer
       AudioKit.start()
    }
}
```

I would also like to use SKAction.playAudioFileNamed for the playback of sound effects etc, but when I use it, the playback volume is very low. I assume it has something to do with the scene's mixer node and the AKMixer? Playing sound files using AudioKit is far more complicated than I need.

Do I need to make an extension of SKScene? Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I actually just tested with headphones and the levels are normal using SKAction.playAudioFileNamed. It must have something to do with feedback protection or something?

Comment: Perhaps the audio is being routed to the wrong speaker?  I don't know this for sure, but some people have mentioned that audio can get routed to the ringtone speaker instead?  Perhaps AudioKit is making the main speaker unavailable so sprite kit is doing the best it can?

Comment: You're right! Can't believe I didn't notice that it is going through the phone's earpiece rather than the speaker when headphones aren't plugged in. Is there any way to explicitly connect the audio of the SKScene to the AKMixer?

Comment: I'm looking at something like this maybe, but I'm getting errors: var sceneAudio = AKNode(); sceneAudio.avAudioNode = (scene?.audioEngine.mainMixerNode)! ; mixer.connect(sceneAudio)

Comment: ERROR:    [0x1abca6c40] >avae> AVAudioEngine.mm:404: ConnectMultipleOutputs: required condition is false: [_nodes containsObject: sourceNode]
2017-01-06 11:49:20.456297 MicAnalysisGame[2096:470307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: [_nodes containsObject: sourceNode]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Aurelius was correct in that the AudioSession output route was being directed to the headset. I'm still not sure why this is was the case, but overriding and setting the output worked as follows:

```
        let session = AVAudioSession()

    do {
        try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } catch {
        print("error setting output")
    }
```

This needs to be done after initializing AudioKit components. If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know!